# Firebase web and data population

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've moved from using mongodb over to using Firebase, one of the major headaches I'm finding is that I cannot populate a id field with the corresponding data like you can in mongodb.

An example of this that I'm having is that you have a post and a list of comments, where I'm only storing the uid of the user who created the comment, is there a way that I can automatically populate that field with the users data? What I've been doing is looping over each piece then doing another query to firebase then setting the field. It's getting rather repetitive needing to do this on so many different instances. Another idea was trying to use cloud functions to achieve a similar thing

Eg; listen out for every query with an account field and populate it with the users data, is this possible with the cloud functions over the HTTP requests?

Any insight of this or anything you guys are doing to achieve a similar thing is much appreciated, cheers!